# IterableWrapper is not defined when using WikiText2

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to follow along this tutorial https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/transformer_tutorial.html

I am getting the following error when calling this function.
----> 6 train_iter = WikiText2(split='train')

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torchtext/datasets/wikitext2.py in WikiText2(root, split)
75         )
76
---> 77     url_dp = IterableWrapper([URL])
78     # cache data on-disk
79     cache_compressed_dp = url_dp.on_disk_cache(

NameError: name 'IterableWrapper' is not defined

Here is the code:

```
from torchtext.datasets import WikiText2
from torchtext.data.utils import get_tokenizer
from torchtext.vocab import build_vocab_from_iterator
from torchdata.datapipes.iter import IterableWrapper

train_iter = WikiText2(split='train')
```

Let me know if you have any ideas.. Thanks

Antoine

Answer (score 1):

please try restarting the Environnement which helped me. installing torch data requires a restart.

Comment: I'm using Google Colab, and I lost my torchdataset package upon runtime restart. How can I get around this?